# Max MSP and Computer Keyboard stuff

Tags: max-msp, msp, computer, keyboard, samples

First off, hat's off to whomever decided this was a good idea, because it rocks!

I have a question about Max MSP and triggering samples with the computer keyboard.  I know this can be done fairly easily, but I feel like a dimly lit bulb when trying to do so.  My Max abilities are still sub par at best.

I am looking to create a patch that will have each key on the keyboard trigger a sample and then that keystroke represented in a note pad of some sort.

Perhaps someone has a taste for the pint and barter system?

-Chris

Answer (score 3):

When wanting to map your computer's keyboard, the important objects are: **[key]**, **[keyup]** and **[select]**. In the patches I gave you below, look inside the yellow objects to see how to use them.

I've put two patches together, one is using your keyboard to trigger MIDI notes, and the other is to trigger samples. I've recycled bits from other patches I had made so some of the programming here is a bit pointless in this context.

To copy this code into Max/MSP, copy (ctr+C) all the code that is in the gray box. In Max/MSP, go **File** >> **New From Clipboard** and it will paste the patch for you.

- MIDI triggered by keyboard:

  ```
  ----------begin_max5_patcher----------
  2397.3oc6ct0aiaiEG+YmOED9ot.dB3MQJUzW11m1G18wEK11AAx1LIpQVxv
  RNYRK528kWjskbjrorrmgb0DfXac+O+QdH44HQw+7tISmm+EQwTvOB9UvjI+
  4cSlnWkZESpVdxzUweYQZbgd2ltHe0JQV4zYlsUJ9Rod8qRVl.1s1rsqRxRE
  k5CAUsx0wkKdNI6oG1HVTZtjHD7d3LP0mj.0Wrv6gfOWcLIK0m774+9mX3Zm
  87sk6N8vp09XdVYV7Jg9.96aRhSmVaKEI+gdKAj6wjvPVjZS+0c2o9XlkI8L
  waRg7gTdZd7xUhhBPDruo+HpNgiMIbrdAV6IeT6odzYS8lct780By0b5z8m9
  5fI7dJAFQBudbYM3UQZ9hjx2aEK3twRfgDbcwBFR8IF1NVvAWMtjHKU2JZPJ
  4TSrhMUvnhFx8NIU7pXSQRdVsK9jo0RR5zRU9sImFGwOjljL9IIrdQrrVY5I
  SWJdrOmi70hrC6ud2a7Qy8LIa8FQgzXNtrR30utwaSKencLzb6OFuPz4A2J6
  mL8oMIKyyThnwQpV8tKmr1AsYg5yC5VuGYwqa4fKyySmGu40jhj4ohF4Cxxu
  wYIqhKEkIF8fg6OtjUq2ny6qctDYwxywyEK1jml13TY1xqsrkkhWSVHdKYY4
  y5y0AZ0nR1ZkaZXY0X8mxBqoUVIXd802VMOcYlwCpU6CldrY1wlZzitNezZ6
  zVbsa0MON6ooMtjGWla2Vz0JY9wraAGgWJGM1kVyQxMgi0q85aHFKDo.HHbn
  rDp+R1X8YXItaVRFXYxYG91E.aRmDEakUNiq9hfuO3zDk48kN0joSZAso7GU
  +YkAcP2vBEZGsNOO10sZ0Ydpq.ivv9.CLw0gg4JewUMw01NTtk33DsWB6Qh8
  PeeRSx5paDZ4p1d6TnHe6lE6vckUNnoxWJJJSx12Sve8Ph3nc74jkKa1yKMm
  SVtNWlQVoOvmsJaquxlZorYNkpI9IrwjdPaj6H6Onl1U8EBaNSUK.Bqc+Jjt
  egaXpwl7.hSUzQ0tncE4uhxtZkR8a7UuH9UwxGjWEYM3ODWVtIY91RSEnM7c
  +DdollOONsxm+86yTqbBtyUdN2o6PKc4Q9cGnv0JrMuHdun0P1.6NjMXTk8f
  pa6lNLf6HPVcDwF7kEwlYmJvMj6oHXXXT01l+zh7z7M6hNRDM.FEpBLRDhvw
  ApeQg7PJQZSWS7WbPeHgUjfYbpwDWKBKpew8wpSy2C8yHLzOb7kG0Bztfuiz
  FsTz470FAi5tGs3g4a3LmI.FRnhF.TglvUaOTQvwATgCApHVOgJZT.UVzkC0
  np3BYOSwiClFN.lRH8jojwAS4WNSCi5aEpzwASYCfozvdxzfwASCF.Sg8sbJ
  abvT5kyTdPeKmxGGLkL.l169RENNX5.bkhw6a69iCOoXCvSJFom0mhGGNRwF
  fiTAg8r9T7XvOJ0ir.BikXIP9MT8vG.hhjKFJ+IADo9hpdTEUd2K+OBPoWbs
  ulddQizQvCFc9bfS30Ehd8dDGtUe6HQe.OjGIEbiVL4m8YRANVBS1kyTJm2K
  lNRbpiOjGcJJA2OlFLVBR1kyTRynObdlxFKAIa.L0z5m8LkOVBR1.XJrm0mF
  NVBR1kyTLi1OlFMVBR1.XJpmkSIikfjc4LEw6W4T5nIHYCfoj90tOMXrDjrv
  Abmb5GRoikXjMD2n5GRIikPjM.j1Ohh+d.xtpAHCwQ8J.YgeO7XCM68Ew6aW
  eoCQD9takr9A+L5bitnSTmN8pXtLy0Ldjz8RYaksfsrk7+mrcXCZGZUc3lJz
  G1fXB57CQINjzqTKg4viQI0XHfZy.4f6Ti8AkrI1H6.mS1XajM04jsUi1Ghy
  IaaFeLTr6QaaJkntGXNltYVHaUH7bLYysQ1gNmrCsQ1tWE2Q1Hal6YSZScIH
  2qAGjMUcibuVbBrQ1tUKN5dIYCtIL2S2VMTRcLdG3o7NvS4M0S4M0S4MwS4M
  wS4M1S4M1S4skxV+DZ5gurQbKWFz9K5gktawOWunzs1QWOj2s3ftev6POk2g
  dJu8TucPdp2NHlmxalmxaO06Rjm5cIxS8tD4odWh7TuKQdp2ks4ESW96fbPk
  aUbjcraJkQ41b2zPN18kxnbhUJOzAUN0JkycPka0MdvwtAUFka0se0wtEUFk
  a0cf0wtIUFka0MgE4hsDY08gEgcwVhrpQTjS1HpUshhbwVQs5gRQ+BLzojNx
  S6kaK8AzS5lKzWItuFnYuMRydanl81XM6sAa1ai1r2FtYuMdyda.m81HN6sg
  b1ai4r2FzYuMpydaXmQXek3Xek39pOmHe0mSju5yIxW84D5q9bB+l3y42m3j
  52DmTWSA5kOK.4KJkzC7Ttn3GA+2h+yxe4e+zO+7+52+mf7Lv6xLb0rqz773
  MKA+vh30Ef3MBvuM8smSJE+1T8TuzLPwp3zzpsLOMdwKUa4us6RpJSsHeqYD
  4h64jNt4kULWOt8wl2HrDZGyUSzqwbt9NZekmt0CfvdOgqiXl2nDlYCU9Imw
  0Ct4y35XXDKH35glr7Rg7h2JTHm.JlAJNw7pbH3zy253ugkH5xv6m9zm.EhR
  vxsazUTBxeDnXAHICrp3dv+3QkoGnnLeMPMuWUHS+J6QkAqztZFHoDT7Vhp1
  pB4w9HHN682hkquHGjlK2W0IyXpNWlwJ1zpcXPOKKV8tPCGVMWWYLKC5f6vu
  kVhaWM+Phtu1ZMlT35pXE5ZOov0XdEui1OjsNlkrZ6JMHudlgqheQnJwbo1g
  lI+LF4T.a+KavgCrGk0npQl4GcxrafA6qhz7EIkuC9AHnLWdU3Wml3PTyqrY
  ptB9H3Iaii6cVVQlWRUTKLrBus1UxDyNCHYl2M0X6khzjkcvJ74lXJwZc.vz
  fSUT.GxNMtrZFn7YYSJMlmIoHDmomcI4zHHV8ivpUUeZlbijr5yKaGwz8J73
  yVHS9GeView4LJG07z83l7+Pj8fDpG0GdorqtTetV1f93Z95awjqbrSLU4Me
  z4k5djXyfN5idrzt2JenbhsJJzBEgaDV6atjBrQRnupTRWn+rhp4cC87hh.0
  utpBB0SPxD59ktJpEYiZ6QtJNfUWt0VZnx0pL7iRSmUtLj4cAVEiY6WZnpEY
  aIAr8hEw0Pk.Mrs1RCTsGUjrC1h+pZLcTAuSnIT+InYBaAE.2uzPUq8kN+Jh
  v.aPXv.zjbg+5t+GKn85P
  -----------end_max5_patcher-----------
  ```
- Samples triggered by keyboard

  ```
  ----------begin_max5_patcher----------
  1910.3oc6a0saihCF85zmBqr6koU3e3uUqzpU6U6KvpU6nQUNAmTZI3Hvoc5
  LZlm8EaSRfDHXHjTR6bCDrA6y2we19y1m7saFMdJ+KrzwfeC7IvnQe6lQiTI
  ISXT9yiFuj9kYQzT0qMdFe4RVrX7DcdB1WDpzSoKWEkUT4oGudYXbDSn9HXd
  hqnhYODFu39D1LgtRw12YMA3IuffpaNYWAeN+KBCTENe5i25fKT170hMEtUd
  py4whX5Rl5C9yjPZz3B4jF9UUN136PXOOGeYVe+lajWlbhl9ue6sf+F735TA
  XIc0JV.3+R+2f+5el.dkuFLiFClyih3u.DOv.Y7DCrJILdVXFeADb42nx4kG
  3YI7D60obZRvlZIJLlMiuNVUUnVxtPhijRgPKEAa6JugIUSv198AACQ2Y0At
  Ml8RFFNzqJbwO.v15T4qrVhx0hfUOXUiM6VsMCazl0ur30ULccJgZbV1aqky
  GoH.oBZhHhyW0VlwQ4A.IPUOsiSMj9iZ1B29jcpq6nrh9i1RLPeMYfrZ1og3
  9F1QQvWrHh0ZyyEWXHVsQVq4Ye7F9CZdCkCN84NXKKYoozErJaAA+Z0c6QMa
  jZuaakQBqY1DBt27tuHN0x4XnAAxYTR.7WhA4y2BdfkzduAKEQ45oYHxw7Fv
  CvYEVAltd9bVR0QaXUugqmNTa25ICq0r6s93EQCKI2Xys1r2NLh8blkDxiKz
  nMZ7NLiTSi4nlSygnGdxq.py3vEQ7YOwBJfuQiCXyaSYvWwh289p2nzkxuYX
  7pDVZleJUjC7h0Kccj39pogx4OmNiU6GWI6NZ7hjv.drDDk9RYxaptLGbk8J
  utC2p2HltphOVv4QSoIOGlFNMhUpcHy+jFGtjJXhPMdPVa+tvkx.4DkJKVLM
  qLdHcVRVLekJJcNOWQNArmCmwdILP7fpr1wVkBOufeSodNkR+X8f1eTVZvTZ
  7hhYV0HH00YJe.VK0MmClR4fdTN6UQGNp6w6YU8nuJKnTcV03Ni1L1i9GS5H
  aVdBqxzYBaUTl+L34vorzaov6ngyqkZQGmZgVpwjwNHc3616OU1AjK5rPtCJ
  hkFK3w8AqBUi7662HoBe+SpOxiWD8ZOvpH2hCGbTZ058OslPCiSEgyd5zX17
  0jniSChahYQ9u+YVYPT7mXrSiX0Lpa9tiz3HAHuqah8HQAnij9G4qmvoqAC.
  sTyQg8T27caJZ.zQhF.0cFcdVPMYKd5BGVfwzqc2oW8TW5EvX.8R9HRujSz6
  E44ZH8h+HRu3Sz6EoWwPyzKz6iH8hNQ5E56YH89dZrWShYHHY8R4dJ1Cg4BQ
  PCiY.h+fDy.7T8aIl52BGf9s61fI4I0Uyd0nLdY9Uy6o70Iy1.mM9Nfx7P.K
  a8Dwa2usOsiR16EeHLHn79aoZZCCVwCiE4.Tuc8M5ozVbKiS1Lb6Lrvsuo31
  aPga4RoMB2H7vB2PSwMYXgajo3dX4eicL0+Fechaj2UJt8uNwcEC7bcfa3UJ
  tQ8HtySLy.zGMYJ8YVv8YUSVjY2SEhjvoqE5PYJcTkG4P4h3SoQ4Gw412YrQ
  m4WsI1zoGVCVp6.HuYGKzSxTHkI5fJEbTagCBC2Izj5Do.lLLEo.6qAzY+ns
  FNQq9Lr5LsxEmkc0FdcG9d+IgfEIb9yrsKgAfpzZvMYMHOqB6MeshInZyA2Y
  QlMohecADd1Jo5DSuUyYsV6EZomku06VP8QaTMggplvPcQ5YRQxsQdpN0vR3
  6HY.yyOOuoKlwi3IazBgOw1x2SJCBeH1EYK+Ewx0ifyLjBFPmk3AV6EgPZ4o
  XiztVv1IxCSJkeJyiObx7PpVzsBEs06QCRq.ArZ7MRyh737nCAkEbo13Kcse
  ZDFJmpr2bsKZLnXbcazEnJtpdzXKq2vC0b3lsPUO94u.l9pRq5x1N.et524Z
  wSI1cZBCrNMiQ.EKwRZXG2U4FoU2YtV1gt53m5nNCrL1W7sYGVEm54wR7yYq
  ZT58EZ2p2eZ2A.k14yfk.cZEktUl3mCJ0dHQoc9bWwX21Qo1mQJkLjnzNeVq
  HmbcX4ZHkRNiTJdHQoc+7U0hZIWNVFPomywRQCIJs6G8WtX1zm.nATJ5LRov
  g.klxhxpMjTruY2sjBoD36m8nWmGIXiP+0KRxqIN9Hhtv8D0m8DyuODZKdh8
  555WwjkIK.PK0Ea+6ravwtdRmzcRWtZ0IUcaXPtclZI4ysYF2heexsm15Sgt
  ZsXAIls.0iI0s1r.02VcRLzN+aCgs204oeOvNkMxawgr0CvFcc5bStR6TRHW
  o319JE2tWm3VNnr80mVZLUZdDzfC1PSf8visQl.axfC1XSfs8fC1DSfs6OkQ
  SuKiFEcVNpdsFC1uULWoAGp91hMJ0EaVo24fFspavNP0CsAQvlPDocPBh8TK
  XUu+.t1ae3BfU6tgUHVsHQWmsObhXEa.VcK8NMCUKrDcXnZ6.7PaenGfpkAP
  8x4TtmC2PneBA2+PBpaCk+exytY6r8gSEq1FfUxkk+rOCMo48V871QepGNUn
  5dNZp0Mtps+eSKMduQYxd3627+7OuiSK
  -----------end_max5_patcher-----------
  ```
- Sample triggered by keyboard, but no need to stay pressed. Staying pressed changes the volume. read the comments in the patch for more details.

  ```
  ----------begin_max5_patcher----------
  2681.3oc6cs0iqhiD94z+JrxtiVsyltE1lqiVoUi1mlmWoQq1ybzQNAmzLMA
  GAjtOYFMme6qu.ogDf3.DZHZdnSB2Le9qJWtbUEz+9Cyluj8UZxbvO.9DX1r
  e+gYyj6RriYYaOa9VxWWERRjm17UrsaoQoyWnNVJ8qox8GwRAoOSAKoIof2H
  GV.VtOE7S+sWE6hFARdlwRCh1HOo2dlERA9jC.RjO+j1BRYL.8qOS1mjR84a
  wOsfnW.6hY6nwgG.+vi+87aYXPDcEaej79hy1YfuDErk+5iNl4m4ZVTZDYKU
  dneLNfDlejcjzU7avluDSWkp59XL7IiE.j7SSCr3KGimL.eN6Zh1uMHJjlJ4
  AXgaQRvuIuEP2mvtXCr26W.aeZ9UXH14e7vChOVzQx9e93iff0fCr8bpNRQ7
  7KD7JKb+Vpf9VRAIrsTAKtAPCSnK.AQxy6SbXsjF+Y91I638dVL3W4rNX0yj
  nMz7lJX69s.N52wEhBoAiKoNnZskzz2DRTCovCZXXznjYWLMg2GHoArnhzsm
  qfgwlRh1H6iijcQ4IrUxSjskTd5oDqdlR4p6UIPQ7q4VKK+Obg0AE6KXWDGk
  B45JRTQQRRJINMS99DnRBG0LgaZIIYjq4EIbi1M.B4IuAVRIJBaqjueXD95P
  FuQxArpwROripPq3vDtz.LeImjmWEOX60NEOKjpmKU7xXcidgFP8rMDglEx.
  7LMlBBR.DPrTgislO3lOjWL19ItcDkoC9IrhHLjvuhsTRTB.8chSMWo7GyrF
  HZoui+irCr.vsvvoheI5WhpTu0rBl2nSlvMbKnAZi9vz.inuw6Mmw7IAa9Vs
  pk7CFw6jUoOhaGqfflEzGw3dTeD1ejRJGS0RJABMkJXDDtcLhmWA8jbklwFi
  78B6yFvKX.qJZA1I8DnbXioWyrB5CSOYYsLRsVxQVsiQbkJHPGGIWX9QqmHc
  bqwAImMcVlqbxaI21bETCpKJKHOznXRtZTVBtdKJszFqkZ3hijHvnmrFiic9
  GWMc.85j1gsyXlNjdfPiECLtzfp7+pkmb6DOgk7jyELvXcM7jYeZx85mYF5z
  JBAprm.yFNYNV8UAd8DhcK0PviIBIksYSH8567VZzEcO14zoKdyDtaoowL9L
  ZWuWFPbWDwYdiZ4NN8656a0RVZmRODplF0EMlm9ncLR67D0FOlHj5BoPBY6t
  PZx7JzCZ2PCkek1p3xJGXXeUAvyB+DB65ZOLQj8mTARcKY2NpO3+k7e8+2+7
  6AyaMKLj8lJXd79OXWbPzp.NeIhzB+ZJDX7WnGVxHw9MFluh5TsyKMnsbkuv
  rvkX47AGvtFBWRCS31zXs14DR1rrpHSaNZiWhLjvgL1t5olimQkrS6xSB2aY
  oVioL751ezzScCHEc6+UEVhLaoioYKwEg5ckBigyOLyl7CChy5hFCqeXaoII
  jMzJkff+Z8C7qtG1tIZx66JAqRVCcGcSvJlkg36KlSIFvdKBjMiqLB9Unria
  4DCp4ZcrOwu7w07B6.K2udMMtJ+MvsaTtZBQU+VMcX8caiqpaW7dRiy5rY8V
  daDDRek2SBXQEXzYyKFfIo0V4p.sMMT4xr.13b3lP1pWn9Etcyl6SWeMsAaG
  M58y2nXhBKksP0YFDULUimdeI6CS+R0jS4iulrhV6EWona17MwA9rHAHJckh
  cme6D1rUKctHtkmQDYWEWbJiEtjD+ZPRvxPZI4.W+jDErkjRSCT3AYb75B1J
  bkKsTaQiH7134jUwbu9J0Tpi7ZEGwm9ZvJ5aA9oOKaq2YqREoQA8lRibJs+l
  FAcpUVhubEsENXyK48rwZ1Eu15EZM5ielWE1mMqSs1aZXvWcVgmka6Q8iEsj
  MKOgUY5LltKjqOCdMXIM4QB7IRv5Fo15oUTmnUngJaN1p.pkMVvsIhEMEHVR
  TJKpCrJrWXUnbxAUZDuCH0ekEsI7PGXUi9fUyxdR9BLl9zZLIHJIMX0KsmYQ
  dcjYUqTAoRjYdjVm7LqvIJ1KTZGHV2NRrYoFV4iLbJXInAu.TdR+sr0SX2Hk
  VcgScF+Z2Q90REwS4WdN2H2BPeDzqUePul8x7Xl12ezqYePu39P6E45b+Qu3
  dfdgt8h+BpkNbeQun9fds6C5EppP6IA8piOC9w62JhoX68Y.h6EdU8HFbm4y
  .rOza6kEmAMGd812CvjHWc0DqFIjEGuZdOgsOdUNgkGXEPYz6S4qmH5X719z
  6gJ3jS74.e+xw2RJZC72wBhRy.H3yZoob6vMbhhaioItEKlbRha2oItEyWLl
  vMRW91dbgant31bbgaCcw83ROoByD0neOtFWVgYhZv83R+tByD0f69b9xrcx
  6.pTSlPdk5+E9sg6O0WHoowAK2mpbkoXpJ6Zl6Z3PWJogaBYKIgYoP8XaTpk
  OCQm1VO7NKzSkoPBM8pqRAb6J8FGjpZwMduFT9.KRA5u4SV8sJR9tyEKjQSC
  0yXjU9mM2EtYkPvlXF6U5wkv.PWpJyVTwupT.2txOPIecJFr95K.A70Hfw8Y
  cW7B8PxiJN6RO3D4Q7rxm0lNPRPkFDzP8v6gtTUZrbyJVHKNuvF7LsL7bE0z
  fGD6frD+xzvw0DuP7rpdrsJws3mLgFttUWLontVgGX2rxuR1wbTODwHW30Ui
  G5zJ+YUdbeVkGJsw45j36pp5UkphptfTkJDxR2fmTY0NIORdorImptGCLU4R
  j67xjKOpeJCP+Ew6XAQAVKzzDOz5xWUIpxGSVg1jXJXeh3EvPwVrpWnE8btu
  sbTyiqdjGfNvSeMUzSQsxXXBJXpVoPL+btQAZ0zKiSgUWhxivZJRCJ0RCJ0p
  VJ8XcO2RJEZeGRolZPol0SoVchRwpm5y6LJEqAkhqmR6VZsQ1YUPjy8Dkhzf
  RQ0SocLoUpJvHqPhtWnTnFTJrdJsiklYVYXoRW0TmRSngbbfDkXJ+aCQ46A7
  7DOCAWtjhWn+20JL5VoDfxqCd0hHbuQxBmgQVvWX99cMR6YKK+7upUWuazag
  WOHVdm9XqV6x0uNx0bvH29kZw8glKb5vsMt9zxUbUUVMyd8Xj8JyXvVf5MI0
  9hLUXpQD+EdsOhxTg.1Xcfs0nC1Hcfs4nC1PcfMdzAacxlkIZzAaqoWR8qvB
  wjHIyUXhXZfayIJtwSTbiln3dhVCbZBa2oYETzqJI+YETnxmrjNK6crJ8xmJ
  FyRx74EtSIoRcy65UzcnyEamJxvFtx0DkEeEUvVkaojamkLbsQqkFn8jtzEQ
  aGwDTCHY6M5fT4Jj6lCIDRG8rgkk7zQYZfoIiavvwtxSt5howlrCMrXRKSot
  Cq9jktXBMb7jVXZXMhi0Ybm00MrCgvhYAwNxubU+OYPrwPfU6tfUn5MUee.V
  aMvpy0gUwSukk5+SL7u7bOtQGgpkiNSadcpkXIFQpRKg+Y9FcEpl8OTgFRZE
  pTATXE1CZ.VZpALbC1M0ARlCqAHS7MPhhUolv18cIpbitZ.5Fn80UHUxDR8l
  DGVDoyDJCnu.ZvQmXX4xpXVYSXnd7OyLgndQldyAKtkf0QNdvEdbid.qWzeF
  mQmrFNrCHf5L8JxZ7gI3.iI6aMl3a7GO7+cDAb4D
  -----------end_max5_patcher-----------
  ```

**UPDATE:**

- To make the sample change (or rotate through a bunch) when repeating the same key, then check the code below. I only gave you the [p keys-sample] subpatch, so you'd replace the one from above with this one. Also, i only showed you one example. You'd have to repeat the same logic for all of them. If you want the sounds to start from the first sample every time, you'll have to add some programming. You could use the object [thresh] to reset if the key is not pressed for X amount of time and make that reset the [counter] object. Here's the patch:

  ```
  ----------begin_max5_patcher----------
  1086.3ocyXt0ipaCDG+Y3SwnzG5K.J9VtTUUo9cnOzpUqpLDyR5lKnDy4rzi
  Ne2quD1k8f2Rf0jvCfwNNN+meY73Y3aSmDrr9EQa.7KvCvjIea5jIlgzCLoq
  +jfR9KqJ3sloErptrTTIClYulT7hzLd9ZXe8N3q7JIH2Hf15cUYsfrFZk7FI
  rtotzbg04MsRP7EQydYdoXl9194hBXC+KB8z4YYpatT.aapepgWVlW8zB3uT
  q8p5cEYvtVgYcpW9OhUR3A4lFQa6i5aU8CgDTJQe8mE6g7VnpVpVI0LDYv55
  F3OAdoRZRnVMM0yeA7GaDUPI+YA7vJ8UDMOZWoC1XQdkvbEsgF0MX0N0xHKD
  RCVB6FccckrhWJLH42ax4EGVjsb4pMJS4uaTp1BbFZQ3L.gi0MXaSR5hP3wt
  6IOyrNJKcNBEbzinM+eMOBDdQ3a5Iu5fbP5w99zo5ul8IewJ2nnnFOsG+dso
  VxkBX97eKve.AkPMDIjYZRSMfIzMQRGKf3xgUQFkaYKubagv3zqlSCrb250h
  lCdpGwp24Qg8H.IgFjYvfBmlFB8Cbohu0DrTssi+jvsGB5ZLPB05gPI5FVn0
  LOx9rO.49sB6MDD3zzYWhoiuBSuR7U0C5DemVQADBH.6lIzqgI33HCFHlvIr
  zEreXSyILYIu5ofYm15lU3asaxGvptfwdkUj3tHLFjESNI.yIrJWGAPgltO5
  ttnTzk.Il+fjrKnCZoO2kEZACxzDkddJ8pHbwF1H4.8Ja3djM3T6o1ogWHa3
  NYCdzXiWcXraqhSLzfddlXh33LZyslGVo7+mzhSKzXTLls4v2tLABJvoX6F7
  PZE5oG3wzR904yUostsfu5PhH+DrbuImM86QS9tpeayIo0jrNuQnRmVYnfyD
  SH9KwjjntcM1lXSCM4C.X3HGvHxiaMhiSONVJouwKhbu8fLxng4SzDhuJzvb
  hFZ7HiFpGQSDlbUng5FMi8IvDOhFFMxRizKCMD2ngNxnA6QzPswUw15m6OZv
  tQyXGqA4yz15JRhkbYnA4FMiUZa55GQXLfPLUqpRxvPHMU0MwMqhuJ2nv32p
  tlPY8LctY8u0ITSFIl9rX+tsdsFSiKFquUi2Ug4oMN87tDHE5UH4QD04gY+a
  p7NiH2ZFck0PPYlirHo8nHBL4pJhvrTlr3+g+Teibzi+dypsdWypCPtqdT3M
  AkIZk4UbYdc0wyg7tIsIOKSTcrsWlmssV81oSCviNYbekD69SRHx8ml5ijRF
  TEQ6ghzEKOjR5V3eiSXlHXwlCLoQIu16yp16P2LJ8NTS2ggHzkiduoI81e1Y
  jDZ3kD5LRhN7RBeNIQGbIQNmjXCtjnmSRwCtjN2Ntg83FTOTTzfpnn9vH7kI
  IRBQehGBa+6+smFZ58YwWeNslhupSqQzT+nuyE8BOrdb3dD8hc+4xwdGIuLI
  o578o+G.igaYz
  -----------end_max5_patcher-----------
  ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I'll check out the patch today and see if it's what I need.

Comment: This patch is great! However, the only other thing I'm looking for is to have the whole sample triggered by the key without having to hold it down. Yet, for the hold down I was hoping to add an increase in volume (sort of velocity sensitive). -Chris

Comment: To have it keep playing, just delete what is connected to the [outlet] 1 of the yellow sub-patch called [p keys-sample]. 

For the volume, you can add a [line~] object to a [*~] object just before your [dac~]. To have it start when you trigger, connect the outlet of [p keys-sample] to trigger the message of the [line~]. Check the help file for [line~] to see what messages it needs. 

Does this make any sense? Do you need a patch?

Comment: I'll try your directions - awesome stuff, and I can't thank you enough! after I am all through, I hope you enjoy free beer. -C

Comment: damn, still confused - seems as if my understanding of max is a hurdle I simply cannot jump over. patch?

Comment: I added a third patch to the answer. Let me know if that's what you mean. Don't hesitate to ask for more help.

Comment: Andrew, Seriously your patch is a life saver! I suppose the only thing I need to tweak is having each sample not stopped when triggering another. I want each sample to play all the way through when pressed, not cut out when pressing another key. I am also at this point unsure how I'll credit you in my work. -Chris

Comment: I'll be toiling away with the poly~ tutorial tonight. Thanks again and I'll get back to you soon. -Chris

Comment: Andrew, While I work away at poly, I have another query. I would like to have different samples triggered by the keyboard dependent on the number of times a key is pressed. I have tried to attach a number box to the samples, but it doesn't seem to work. My idea is to have sounds evolve from key touching. For instance, if, the P key is pressed, say, 3 times, the sound it triggers will change to a different sample. -Chris

Comment: Also, on a side note, I am going nuts connecting each key to a single sample. I am going nuts because it isn't really necessary. I would much rather have each key play a sample at random from a large sample bank. I imagine this is very possible - how though? -Chris

Comment: I thought you wanted the keys mapped to specific samples. Very possible. Make like easier. Look maybe at the help patch for [coll] so you can type in quickly the name of all your sound files. Check also [random] or [urn] to trigger a new  sample every time. I gave you enough in the main patch for you to be able to hack your way into adapting it for your needs. I can't do all your patching :-) suffering through it is honestly the best way to learn!

Comment: Ah! I didn't mean a random bank of samples for all of the keys. I meant that I want each key to have its own bank of samples (with each press choosing at random one of the samples). -Chris

Comment: I have max 6 and this code will not work. Could someone perhaps send me this in a code that is compatible with max 6????

Comment: Strange... works for me. I'm sure that copy compressed patches are forward compatible. Where does it go wrong? Are you definitely copying the whole text - including begin/end max patcher?

Answer (score 0):

If im guessing correct you want to connect your keyboard and trigger something. If yes then u might need a ctlin object and then connect it to a select object (sel 1) so you will get only the notes on. the select object gives you bangs as output. and then sorry i cant understand what you want to do...my english sucks!